# Windows 10 CMD Batch How to delete specific folders

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

Iv'e got a directory
**%userprofile%\appdata\roaming.minecraft\versions**
and in that directory is a whole heap of folders, i want a batch file to delete all the folder with **forge** anywhere in there name.

there are no subfiles in these folders, but there are 2 files in each... i want anything in that directory with **forge** in it's name deleted automatically with a batch file.

so delete all folders including **forge** in there name. i cant seem to do it.

This is all i know so far ^^^

I have tried googling stuff, but i cant remember everything i have tried... but here is some.

**rmdir /s %userprofile%\appdata\roaming.minecraft\versions**

**for /d /r . %d in (forge) do @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d"**

also tried this (below) but it only listed the folders and files i want deleted.

**dir "%userprofile%\appdata\roaming.minecraft\versions" /s /b /d | find "forge"**

Comment: Why don't you use File Explorer?  Why do you want to use the command prompt?  What have you tried?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: Also, are these folders all always empty with no files beneath, or could they contain files as well including subfolders with files?

Comment: Use [`FOR /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)

Comment: so for FOR /D what excact code would i use? im a litte comfused

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: When we say “tell us what you have tried so far”, that doesn’t mean “tell us everything else you have done”.  We don’t care what you had for breakfast or where you went on vacation last year.  We want — no, we *expect* — you to try to solve your problem on your own, and then show us that attempt.  The code you posted does not qualify as an attempt to solve your problem on your own.

Comment: the program "EVERYTHING SEARCH" by voidtools is the answer to this question...

Comment: Are you sure i cant do it in a batch file? like i know CMD is a basic launguage but still im pretty sure it's got the capability.